# How can I read an email's body text with Chilkat and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, email, imap, chilkat

So, I currently have a node.js project that uses chilkat in order to read emails. Currently it does most of what I'm looking for, returning the subject, header, and the email address of each email. The only thing I can't get to return is the body text. Currently when I try to do so, it returns either an empty of `null` result.

I know why the problem happens. It's because I am only fetching email header info here before trying to print the result:

```
var bundle;
bundle = imap.FetchHeaders(messageSet);
if (imap.LastMethodSuccess == false) {

    console.log(imap.LastErrorText);
    return;
}

var i = 0;
while (i < bundle.MessageCount) {
    // email: Email
    var email;
    email = bundle.GetEmail(i);

    console.log(email.GetHeaderField("Date"));
    console.log(email.Subject);
    console.log(email.From);
    console.log(email.Body);
    console.log("--");

    i = i+1;
}
```

So, I know the fix should happen here, but for the life of me I can't find what should go in place the the `imap.FetchHeaders()` part.

Comment: [This example](https://www.example-code.com/nodejs/imap_fetchMimeIndividually.asp) suggests using [`FetchSingle`](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/nodejsImapRef.html#method36) or [`FetchSingleAsMime`](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/nodejsImapRef.html#method37).

Comment: Have you tried using `FetchBundle()` in place of `FetchHeaders()` ? The point of fetching only headers in IMAP is so your client program can inspect them and then decide whether to fetch whole messages. It looks like you don't need that level of sophistication in this application.

Comment: @O. Jones Thank you! That definitely did it. Also, yes, you do have a point. I'll have to keep that in mind moving forward, but for now I'm just happy I got this much working. Out of curiosity, would it be better to use a different library for fetching the whole email after chilkat does its thing?

Answer (score 0):

Use `FetchBundle()` in place of `FetchHeaders()`.